# Remove an automatic title in a plot (R)

Tags: r, plot

I am using a function "lp_lin_panel" from the package "lpirfs", for example:

```
hor3.1_h <- lp_lin_panel(data_set = panel_3 , data_sample = "Full" , endog_data = "E.tertiary", cumul_mult = TRUE , shock = "lv18_bank_c", diff_shock = FALSE , iv_reg = FALSE , instrum = NULL , panel_model = "within" , panel_effect = "individual" , robust_cov = "vcovSCC" , use_gmm = FALSE, gmm_model = "onestep", gmm_transformation = "d", c_exog_data = cv_3_h, l_exog_data = NULL, confint = 1.96 , hor = 6  )
```

When I use the command:

```
plot(hor3.1_h , main = NULL)
```

I still get an automatic title in the plot. Like this

[image]

Is there another way to remove it?

Thank you

Comment: @akrun I just added the plot. The automatic tittle is "Shock on E.tertiary". It does this with every plot and I can not remove it

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/AdaemmerP/lpirfs/blob/master/R/lp_lin_panel.R) makes no mention of `main=`. The `lpirfs` package imports `ggplot2`. Have you tried adding `ggplot`-like labeling?

Comment: @r2evans I tried some functions. But ggplot() only accepts data frame. And I can not convert "lpirfs_lin_panel_obj" to a data frame. Do you recommend any specific function in the package of ggplot2?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used the package. I found no reference in the source (in my cursory look) to change the title, so ... if you don't hear from somebody else here, you may want to reach out to the authors.

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/AdaemmerP/lpirfs/blob/master/R/lpirfs_obj-methods-base.R) code, `plot()` actually seems to just call `plot_lin()` that produces a ggplot object. So if you call `plot_lin(hor3.1_h)+ggtitle("")` I expect you would get the result you want.

Comment: @Alexlok it gives this error "  non-numeric argument to binary operator ".

Comment: If you use `plot_lin(hor3.1_h)` it will return a *list* of `ggplot` plots, not a single plot. So, try something like `my_plots <- plot_lin(hor3.1_h)` and then see if when you extract an individual plot you can remove the title, for example: `my_plots[[1]] + ggtitle("")`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
plot(hor3.1_h) + labs(title = "")
```